# Whenever I clicked on a button a new div is created

Tags: javascript, html, css, appendchild

When the button is clicked, a new div is added. Each time it is clicked an additional div is added. The div have following properties:

1. It has a class box
2. For the text inside the div, number the div starting with 1.(Keep a counter variable to track what number comes next.)

I hope these pic might help you:

[image]

Comment: What is this? Explanation of how non-existent code works? We are not here to create everything for you. Provide us what have you done? What question is it that you have? Where is a problem etc.?

Comment: Please provide more info. [A minimum reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help us help you with your problem.

Comment: I suggest you start researching [eventListeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Answer (score -1):

HTML:

```
<button onclick="newDiv()">Add Box</button>
<div id="parent"></div>
```

JS:

```
function newDiv() {
  var divElem = document.createElement("div");
    elementAttr.setAttribute('class','divclass');
//if you want to add text inside
    //var imText = document.createTextNode("Hello Wolrd");
   // divElem.appendChild(imText);
//you need a parent Div to put this inside
    var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
    parent.appendChild(divElem);}
```

just make a css class with a style that you want so when a div is made it will get a style.